# Selecting pairs of numbers from a dataframe

Tags: r, rhdf5

I have a dataframe like this:

```
row   col
1     1
1     50
1     55
2     75
```

and I want to select all the row and col values that are paired so I can insert them into a function.

I am trying this code:

```
library(rhdf5)

 for(row in df$row){

  for (col in df$col){

      apixel = h5read("C/path_to_a_file',, index=list(1, col, row))
      apixel= data.frame(apixel)
 }
}
```

This is inserting all my `row` and `col` values from my df like I want, but it is doing every possible combination of them  I only want to insert the appropriate pairing.  For instance, `row` 1 should only ever be paired with `1`, `50` and `55` as a corresponding `col`, not `75`.

Possibly I could try to zip the two columns and then return the associated tuples?

Comment: you may try something like df[df$row==row,] in the inner for loop to isolate the expected rows.

Comment: You only need to loop over the rows, not the columns. By doing both row+col you get all combinations.

Comment: @thelatemail that makes sense, but I am not sure how I select the actual value in the col then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step: write the function so as it accepts pairs of (row, col) as an argument:

```
read_pixels <- function(row, col) {
  require(rhdf5)
  apixel <- h5read("C/path_to_a_file',, index=list(1, col, row))
  apixel <- data.frame(apixel)

  # do something with apixel
}
```

Now you can pass each row of the data frame to your function. There are various ways to do that, here is an ugly one using `apply`:

```
apply(myDataFrame, 1, function(x) read_pixels(x[1], x[2])
```